# Differences between BP1 and BP2 or BP3 - W3C Data on the Web Best Practices

Tags: semantic-web, w3c, linked-data, opendata

I'm starting to study about the [W3C Best Practices on Linked Open Data](https://www.w3.org/TR/dwbp/).

And I'm stuck with an issue regarding the initial best practices

- **Best Practice 1**: Provide metadata -> *Provide metadata for both human users and computer applications*.

vs.

- **Best Practice 2**: Provide descriptive metadata -> *Provide metadata that describes the overall features of datasets and distributions* (both machine- and human-readable).
- **Best Practice 3**: Provide structural metadata -> *Provide metadata that describes the schema and internal structure of a distribution* (both machine- and human-readable).

By providing evidence on BP2 or BP3, can I assume that BP1 is also met (i.e., BP1 is redundant)?

Answer (score 1):

By my reading, satisfying either BP2 or BP3 would also satsify BP1, but BP1 might also be satisfied *without* satisfying either BP2 or BP3.

So, BP1 is not strictly redundant.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @TallTed!. Yeah, I considered that. But they provided some evidences from [use cases](http://w3c.github.io/dwbp/dwbp-implementation-report.html#list-of-evidence) in which this proposition is not true (i.e. some satisfying BP2 or BP3 are not satisfying in BP1).

Comment: OK, so each apparently *can* be satisfied without satisfying the others.  Thus, they're *not at all* redundant, and I wonder why your question was even asked. (Note that the [Implementation Report](http://w3c.github.io/dwbp/dwbp-implementation-report.html) does not describe a set of generic Use Cases, but a set of live implementations.) Further questions are probably best brought to [those directly involved](mailto:public-dwbp-comments@w3.org).

Comment: Yes, apparently they can be satisfied independently, since they are different BPs. My original question was a request for help to try to understand the reason why, since the text is not clear to me. Even the implementation report does not provide clarity on the evidences. Thanks anyway for trying to answer.